# Convergence of $a_n=d(u_n,\Bbb{Z})$ where $u_n=\bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigr)^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

> I would like to  study the sequence defined by 
>   $$
> a_n=d(u_n,\Bbb{Z}).
> $$
>
> Where $u_n=\bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigr)^n$ and $d(u_n,\Bbb{Z})=\inf\{d(u_n,x):x\in\Bbb{Z}\}$.

I do not really have ideas, here is some 'though',

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=d(u_{n+1},\Bbb{Z})-d(u_n,\Bbb{Z})=\inf(\{d(u_{n+1},x):x\in\Bbb{Z}\})-\inf(\{d(u_{n},x):x\in\Bbb{Z}\}).$$

Now by theorem I have $\vert d(u_{n+1},\Bbb{Z})-d(u_n,\Bbb{Z})\vert\le\Vert u_{n+1}-u_n\Vert$.

Let us compute $\Vert u_{n+1}-u_n\Vert=\Vert\bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigr)^{n+1}-\bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigr)^n\Vert=\Vert\bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigr)^n\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}2\Vert.$

---

After that I am not sure what I have to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that 
$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$
is an integer. The second term has limit $0$.

**Remark:** There are many ways to show that our expression $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ is an integer. One way is by induction, using the fact that
$$\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}=(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha^n+\beta^n)-\alpha\beta(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1}),$$
and $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$ are integers.

Another way is to show that each of $\alpha^n$ and $\beta^n$, and therefore their sum, satisfies the recurrence $x_{n+1}=x_n+x_{n-1}$. Then from the fact that $\alpha^0+\beta^0$ and $\alpha^1+\beta^1$ are integers, we can conclude that $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ is an integer for all $n$. By the way, these are the *Lucas numbers*, close relatives of the Fibonacci numbers.

Whenever $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ has a problem, its conjugate $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is ready to pitch in and help.

Comment: Oh great idea, using Binomial theorem I think I got it. So I have to replace that $(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n=k-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n$?

Comment: The Binomial Theorem will work, but it leads to some complications because of the denominator $2$. You need to prove that the the $n$-th power has shape $\frac{a\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$, which is not entirely obvious, since the "natural" denominator is $2^n$.  But for the rest, the fact that $\alpha^n+\beta_n$ is an integer $k_n$ shows essentially immediately that the distance from $\alpha^n$ to the nearest integer approaches $0$, indeed fairly fast.

Comment: Right, I concluded too fast. I am reading your remark, thank you for this method.(+1)

Comment: I had typos in the previous comment, wanted has shape $\frac{a\pm b\sqrt{5}}{2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers. Also had $\alpha^n+\beta_n$, and $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ was intended.